# How to apply kernel patches

Tags: software-installation, kernel, patch

I've been installing kernels from [mainline repository](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4-wily/) - all simple there, just `*.deb` files, one can do simple `dpkg -i` on them. But how can one apply the patches `0001-base-packaging.patch` , `0002-debian-changelog.patch`, `0003-configs-based-on-Ubuntu-4.4.0-0.10.patch` manually ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As stated in [README](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4-wily/README) at [mainline](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4-wily):

> These binary packages represent builds of the mainline or stable Linux
>   kernel tree at the commit below:
>
> ```
> v4.4 (afd2ff9b7e1b367172f18ba7f693dfb62bdcb2dc)
> ```
>
> To obtain the source from which they are built fetch the commit below:
>
> ```
> git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel-test/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/mainline-crack v4.4
> ```
>
> and apply the following patches on top in the order below:
>
> ```
> 0001-base-packaging.patch
> 0002-debian-changelog.patch
> 0003-configs-based-on-Ubuntu-4.4.0-0.10.patch
> ```

This means that you need to apply those patches only if you are building your kernel from source and not from `*.deb`.

In case if you are building it from source, then these are the steps you need to follow:

1. Install these packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install git build-essential kernel-package fakeroot libncurses5-dev
   ```
2. Get the source code:

   ```
   mkdir anyname; cd anyname
   git clone git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel-test/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/mainline-crack v4.4
   ```
3. Copy the patches files.
4. Change to kernel directory:

   ```
   cd v4.4
   ```
5. Make any custom changes.
6. Apply patches:

   ```
   patch -p1 < ~/anyname/0001-base-packaging.patch
   patch -p1 < ~/anyname/0002-debian-changelog.patch
   patch -p1 < ~/anyname/0003-configs-based-on-Ubuntu-4.4.0-0.10.patch
   ```
7. Make:

   ```
   cp /boot/config-`uname -r` .config
   gedit .config

   make oldconfig
   make menuconfig

   make clean
   make -j `getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN` deb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-custom
   ```
8. Install generated deb:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i ../*.deb
   ```
9. Update `GRUB` and reboot:

   ```
   sudo update-grub; sudo reboot
   ```

Comment: So in short, if I'm using the `*.deb` files, patches are already there ?

Comment: @Serg - Yes! right.

Comment: I do not think the package list is complete. For example, and as of kernel 4.3 `libssl-dev` is needed.

Comment: After oldconfig runs, the config is much different then the one provided by the mainline kernel (eg: extracting boot/config-xxxx from linux-image-xxxx.deb). It would be desirable to have identical config vs. the one that shipped.

Comment: forgot to do the important part 
"git checkout v4.4"
you compile the main branch  not v4.4